# How the hardware platform impacts upon the choice for the programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, hardware

Long put short: The teacher who taught me through out the last year has only recently left and has been replaced with a new one. This new teacher has given me an assignment that involves things (like this) that we were never previously taught. So this task has showed up on the assignment and I have no idea how to do it. I can't get hold of the teacher because he's poorly and not coming in for the next few days. And even when I do ask him to explain further, he gets into a right mood and makes me feel like I'm completely retarded.

> Describe how the hardware platform impacts upon the choice for
>   the programming language

Looking at my activity here on SO, you can tell that I'm into programming, I'm into developing things, and I'm into learning, so I'm not just trying to get one of you guys to do my homework for me.

Could someone here please explain how I would answer a question like this.

Comment: Look at 10 different well known hardware platforms. What languages supported and/or recommended by platform vendor? What languages is used? Whu that language is choosen on this platforms?

Comment: If nothing else, this is a good example of how to phrase a question to ensure your homework gets completed for you! ;)

Comment: I respect your skills & really liked this "Looking at my activity here on SO, you can tell that I'm into programming....". However the question that your teacher has asked is IMO a very irrelevant question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some considerations below, but not a full answer by any means.

If your hardware platform is a small embedded device of some kind, then your choice of programming language is going to be directed towards the lower level unmanaged languages - you probably won't be able to (or want to) load a managed language runtime like the Java JVM or .NET CLR. This is down to memory and storage requirements. Similarly, interpreted languages will be out of the question as you won't have space for the intepreter.

If you're on a larger machine, it's more a question of compatibility. A managed language must run on a platform where its runtime is supported. In the case of .NET, that's Windows, or other platforms if you substitute the Microsoft CLR with the Mono runtime. In the case of Java, that's a far wider range of platforms.

Comment: Your second paragraph is a bit off, since this is hardware platform, not software platform.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines.  For performance, a low level language would be a good choice for an embedded device, because of limited resources.  A high-end hardware platform with plenty of resources would allow one more options.

Comment: Agreed with @nhahtdh. On that level you should talk about platforms available on, say x64 Linux vs. x86 Windows vs. SPARC Solaris vs. PPC OS X etc.

Comment: @nhahtdh. Yes agreed, but because some hardware platforms preclude some software platforms,it's not a total tangent.

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means a definitive answer, but my first thought would be embedded systems. A task I perform on an embedded system, or other low powered battery operated computer, would need to be handled completely different to that performed on a computer which has access to mains electricity.

One simple impact.. would be battery life.

If I use wasteful algorithms on an embedded system, the battery life will be affected.

Hope that helps stir the brain juices!

Comment: After seeing some of the answers here, I think it's more based on the hardware performance and reliability of what specific languages require. Still an awesome answer though! Thanks xD

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, the speed and amount of memory of the device will impact the choice. The more primitive and weak the platform is, the harder it is to run code developed with very high level languages. Code written with them may just not work at all (e.g. when there isn't enough memory) or be too slow or it will require serious optimizations (i.e. incur more work), perhaps affecting negatively the feature set or quality.

Also, some languages and software may rely heavily on or benefit from the availability of page translation in the CPU. If the CPU doesn't have it, certain checks will have to be done in software instead of being done automatically in hardware, and that will affect the performance or the language/software choice.